# How to extract n 1-D tensors from a given 2-D tensor?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a 2-D tensor:

> a = [[6, 5, 4], [3, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 1], [5, 2, 6]]

I want to extract K 1-D tensors **randomly** and **no repeat**. Next , combining them to another 2-D tensor b:

> b = [5, 2, 6], [3, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4]

I don't find any functions doing this, so I implement it as bellow:

```
rand_var_1 = tf.random_crop(a, size=[1, 3], seed=1)
rand_var_2 = tf.random_crop(a, size=[1, 3], seed=2)
rand_var_3 = tf.random_crop(a, size=[1, 3], seed=3)
rand_var_4 = tf.random_crop(a, size=[1, 3], seed=4)
b = tf.concat(0, [rand_var_1, rand_var_2, rand_var_3, rand_var_4])

b_rs = sess.run(b)
print "b_rs:\n",b_rs
```

but the result has repetitive 1-D tensor like:

> bb=[[5, 2, 6], [3, 2, 1], [5, 2, 6]]

Could please someone help me fix this?

Comment: Not sure if this would work with tensorflow, but with NumPy arrays, it could be implemented with : `a[np.random.choice(a.shape[0],3, replace=False)]`.

Comment: This doesn't work in tensorflow, but i have decided to try this: `a_shuffled = tf.random_shuffle(a, seed=12), b = tf.slice(a_shuffled, [0, 0], [K,len(a[0])])`, I think they are doing the same thing to some point. Anyway, thank you for your kind help :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work, basically generate an array of numbers the length of your array `a`, shuffle them and use the first `K` to index and get the rows,

```
import numpy as np

#Number of samples
K = 3

#Array
a =[[6, 5, 4], [3, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 1], [5, 2, 6]]
N = len(a)

#Get an array on size of a, shuffle and take first K to use
#permutation used as suggested by @EelcoHoogendoorn
indices = np.random.permutation(N)

#Take the first k samples
samples = indices[:K]
b = [a[i] for i in samples]

#Print
print('a = ', a)
print('b = ', b)
```

Comment: numpy.random.permutation does the same thing, but more compactly

Comment: Syntax gets a little nicer if you use a numpy array instead of a list of lits (`b = a[samples]`), but yes, this seems to be the obvious approach, +1.

Comment: Good point @EelcoHoogendoorn, I've changed to permutation as suggested. Thanks @Jaime, I agree and used `numpy` arrays for `a`/`b` originally but as OP uses a list, seemed sensible to keep the same format...

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work in tensorflow, I have decided to try another method, see my reply to @Divakar if you are interested. Thank you for your kind help :).